# Infinispan jgroups: discarded message from different cluster "C2" (our cluster is "C1")

Tags: jboss, infinispan, jgroups

The below are the config xml wrt infinispan and jgroups. ${cache.clusterName}" is substituted at runtime with C1 [the configured cluster name] in
Infinispan_config.xml. The C2 is not the one configured to be a cluster [though present as a clustername, there is no code that I could figureout from the code base that replace c1 as C2].
background we are running jboss 7 in parallel with jboss5 as part of migration but for the jboss5 to be in sync with jboss 7 seems it needs to be the same cluster

1) Please point any other repercussion of this warning apart from the additional set of logs. App was unstable post running in parallel in prod. The same build worked fine in lower env

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:4.2 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-4.2.xsd"
xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:4.2">

<global>
    <transport clusterName="${cache.clusterName}">
        <properties>
            <property name="configurationFile" value="jgroups-tcp.xml" />
        </properties>
    </transport>
</global>

<default>
    <locking isolationLevel="READ_COMMITTED"
        lockAcquisitionTimeout="10000" writeSkewCheck="false"
        concurrencyLevel="50" useLockStriping="false" />
    <clustering mode="replication">
        <stateRetrieval initialRetryWaitTime="1000" timeout="10000" numRetries="10"
                        alwaysProvideInMemoryState="true" fetchInMemoryState="true" />            
        <sync />
    </clustering>
</default>
```

jgroups.xml

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups file:schema/JGroups-2.8.xsd">

   <TCP
    bind_addr="${jboss.bind.address}"
    bind_port="${jgroups.tcp.port:7800}"
    loopback="true"
    port_range="30"
    recv_buf_size="20000000"
    send_buf_size="640000"
    discard_incompatible_packets="true"
    max_bundle_size="64000"
    max_bundle_timeout="30"
    enable_bundling="true"
    use_send_queues="true"
    sock_conn_timeout="300"
    enable_diagnostics="false"
    thread_pool.enabled="true"
    thread_pool.min_threads="2"
    thread_pool.max_threads="30"
    thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
    thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
    thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
    thread_pool.rejection_policy="Discard"
    oob_thread_pool.enabled="true"
    oob_thread_pool.min_threads="2"
    oob_thread_pool.max_threads="30"
    oob_thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
    oob_thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
    oob_thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
    oob_thread_pool.rejection_policy="Discard"        
     />

   <!-- Ergonomics, new in JGroups 2.11, are disabled by default in TCPPING until JGRP-1253 is resolved -->   
   <TCPPING timeout="10000"
        initial_hosts="${jgroups.initial.hosts}"
        port_range="0"
        num_initial_members="${jgroups.num.initial.members:4}"
        ergonomics="false"
    />  

   <MERGE2 max_interval="30000" min_interval="10000"/>

   <FD_SOCK/>

   <FD timeout="3000" max_tries="3"/>

   <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"/>

   <pbcast.NAKACK
     use_mcast_xmit="false" gc_lag="0"
     retransmit_timeout="300,600,1200,2400,4800"
     discard_delivered_msgs="false"/>

   <UNICAST timeout="300,600,1200"/>

   <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="1000" desired_avg_gossip="50000" max_bytes="400000"/>

   <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="false" join_timeout="7000" view_bundling="true"/>

   <UFC max_credits="2000000" min_threshold="0.10"/>

   <MFC max_credits="2000000" min_threshold="0.10"/>

   <FRAG2 frag_size="60000"/>

  <pbcast.STREAMING_STATE_TRANSFER/>

   <pbcast.FLUSH timeout="0"/>

</config>
```

Comment: Besides using ultra-old versions, the configuration files seem to be for embedded mode while you use JBoss servers: that doesn't sound right. You should configure those in standalone.xml.

Comment: And the reason why you're getting messages from another cluster is that both operate on the same port. Also I am not sure what are you setting as jgroups.initial.hosts.
Also note that different versions (even micros) of Infinispan are not mutually compatible, you need to use the same JGroups and the same Infinispan.